# Minimize the variance of a Boltzmann distribution

Tags: st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, sampling, learning-theory

**N.B.:** Sorry for cross-posting from https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/347804/edit (I realized it was the wrong venue for the question, but couldn't find an easy way to transfer the question here).

So, consider a set of infintiely-differentiable convex functions $f_i: \mathcal X \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $i$ varies from $1$ to $m$, and suppose
we know all the moments of $f_i(x)$ (and of all the derivatives of $f_i$) for all $i$, as $x$ is sampled from some distribution $P$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal X$.

**Question:**

What is a low-variance estimate for the quantities

$$\mathbb E_{x \sim P}\left[\frac{\exp(f_i(x))}{\sum_{j=1}^m\exp(f_j(x))}\right] ?$$

I mean to replace the integrands $\exp(...)/\sum_j \exp(...)$ with other random quantities of same expectation (or approx the same), but with smaller variance (the smaller the better).

**Particular case: Affine functons.** For simplicity, take $f_i(x) \equiv \langle a_i,x\rangle + b_i$, for some vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_m \in \mathcal X$ and scalars $b_1,\ldots,b_m \in \mathbb R$. Note that in this case, the above sought-for quantity can be rewritten in the form

$$\mathbb \nabla_{b_i} R(b),$$
where $R(b) := E_{x \sim P}\left[\log\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\exp(f_j(x))\right)\right]$. People in finance refer to $R$ as "logarithmic log-returns".

**Important note:**
I should precise that i don't want Monte Carlo (or other black-box simulation technique). I need something more principled which exploits the structure of the problem..

Comment: What is "a low-variance estimate"?

Comment: I mean to replace the integrands $\exp(...)/\sum_j \exp(...)$ with another random quantity of same expectation (or approx the same), but with smaller variance.

Comment: I'm still in the dark about what exactly is asked. If anybody can enlighten me, that would be great.

Comment: @fedja I think the question is pretty clear as it stands. If you can say explictly where you're lost, I should be able to clarify...

Comment: At the same sentence as before: "What is the low-variance estimate...?" Or, if you prefer, at "I seek to replace the integrands...". What are the rules of the game exactly? I doubt you want the answer "replace them with constants exactly equal to the corresponding expectations".

Comment: The whole point is to replace the computation of an expectation (integration is a difficult business, that's why things like importance sampling, etc. exist in the first place) with something simpler to compute, and "not too far from the correct answer" (e.g unbiased estimates). In particular "replace them with constants ... equal to the corresponding expectations"  is void, and won't do the trick. Now, in the space of all such approx, some will've high variance (w.r.t whatever sampling procedures you're using in your approx., some will have low variance. Name of the game is variance reduction

Comment: Give me an example of "such approximation" (I don't care whether the variance is high or low, I just want to see how it can be different from the original expression)

Comment: Indeed, let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be nonconstant unbiased estimates for $\mathbb E f(X)$ (i.e $\mathbb E Y_k = \mathbb f(X)$ for $k=1,2$) which are negatively correlated with one another (i.e $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2) < 0$). Now, consider the variable $Y := (Y_1 + Y_2) / 2$ and note that $Y$ is also an unbiased estimator for $\mathbb E f(X)$ but $\operatorname{var}(Y) = (\operatorname{var}(Y_1) + \operatorname{var}(Y_2) + 2\operatorname{cov}(Y_1,Y_2)) / 4 < \min(\operatorname{var}(Y_1), \operatorname{var}(Y_2)) $. This proper reduction of variance holds even if you take $Y_1 = f(X)$.

Comment: Erm... There are no $Y$' in your setup. To introduce them looks the same to me as to say "Let $Y$ be a constant random variable with the same expectation as...". and you declared that "void". What do you really have at your disposal to operate with? As written, you have $P$ and $f_i$, but nothing else, which means that your answer should be in terms of them alone.

Comment: @fedja There is nothing mysterious about the statement of the problem as it stands. I don't want to waste my time (and your time) debating about idiosyncrasies of the syntax and semantics of an already clearly stated problem. Variance-reduction is a standard topic (lookup google or wikipedia). Also the explanations I've given you should help you get a feel of what the game is about. Cheers!

Comment: Well, let's consider it a total communication failure. I still have absolutely no idea what you are asking but will abstain from voting to close. If some other people can translate the question into "mathematical common", I'll think of it.

Comment: Disagree on the third one. I do understand that you don't understand that I don't understand the question.  :lol: As to "nothing can be done about it", translate it into mathematical common, which is given this, this, and this *and nothing else*, how to construct a function of those given objects (*and no other hidden variables*) to minimize the given functional defined so and so" or something else like that.

Comment: Troll detected. :)

Answer (score 1):

A way to approach your problem could be to consider the calculation of the expectation value as a Monte Carlo integration. Then you can use established techniques of variance reduction, as described for example in these lecture notes [(1)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/Ch-var-basic.pdf) or [(2)](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/MonteCarlo2005/notes/VarianceReduction.pdf).  There is a great variety of techniques, and for many there are ready-to-use software packages that implement the algorithm (for example in MatLab).

Comment: I should precise in the question that  i don't want Monte  Carlo (or other black-box simulation technique). I need something more principled which exploits the structure of the problem...

Comment: Well, you could use the "antithetic" variance reduction technique described in the linked references, which combines points $x$ where the integrand is small with those where it is large to achieve a variance reduction; this exploits the structure of the problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Not quite, as it doesn't use any information given in the problem. My best guess might be to resort to "control variates" cooked using the transformed variables $f_i(x)$). BTW, thanks to one of pdfs your referred has helped me identify that he problem is linked to something  financial economists refer to as "logarithmic returns". So basically my problem is to produce a low variance estimate of the derivative of logarithmic returns. Rather unexpected connection!